# How can I disable other buttons when I press one button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do this in angular? When I press one single button element, other button elements automatically get disabled. I saw a similar question but looking for this in pure angularjs.

```
<html ng-app>
  <button ng-model="button" > abc  </button> 
  <button ng-disabled="button"> def </button> 
  <button ng-disabled="button"> ghi </button>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind an `ng-click` event to all three of the buttons, passing an identifier to the function (i.e. the `id` of the button. Your function would then bind a variable to the scope, which you could then use to determine if `ng-disabled` should be active or not.

For example, in your controller you would have something similar to:

```
    $scope.selectedButton;

    $scope.selectButton = function(id) {
        $scope.selectedButton = id;
    }
```

Then, in your HTML; you would revise it to take in the `ng-click` and `ng-disabled` considerations mentioned above.

```
<html ng-app ng-controller="SomeController">
  <button ng-disabled="selectedButton && selectedButton != 'abc'" ng-click="selectButton('abc')">abc</button> 
  <button ng-disabled="selectedButton && selectedButton != 'def'" ng-click="selectButton('def')">def</button> 
  <button ng-disabled="selectedButton && selectedButton != 'ghi'" ng-click="selectButton('ghi')">ghi</button>
</html>
```

Note, the logic of checking if selectedButton and the selectedButton does not equal `foo`, is to determine that a button has been selected, thus the variable is set to scope.

Comment: Thank you all. I liked this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, pure angular way.

```
<html ng-app>
  <button ng-click="buttonsDisabled = true"> abc  </button> 
  <button ng-disabled="buttonsDisabled"> def </button> 
  <button ng-disabled="buttonsDisabled"> ghi </button>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21811/

Comment: Author didn't say that it should work for every button. Look at his example. There is a difference between "One button" and "Any button".

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="yourApp">
  <body ng-controller="buttonCtrl">
    <button ng-disabled="!button1" ng-click="toggleFunction(1)" > abc  </button> 
    <button ng-disabled="!button2" ng-click="toggleFunction(2)" > abc  </button> 
    <button ng-disabled="!button3" ng-click="toggleFunction(3)" > abc  </button> 
  </body>
</html>

<script>

yourApp.controller('buttonCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  function toggleFunction(activeBtn){
      if (activeBtn == 1){
          $scope.button1 = true;
          $scope.button2 = false;
          $scope.button3 = false;
      } else if (activeBtn == 2){
          $scope.button1 = false;
          $scope.button2 = true;
          $scope.button3 = false;
      } else if (activeBtn == 3){
          $scope.button1 = false;
          $scope.button2 = false;
          $scope.button3 = true;
      }
  }
}]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<script>
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('someCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.mySwitch=true;
  $scope.toggle=function(){
    $scope.mySwitch=!$scope.mySwitch;
  };
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <p>
      <button ng-click="toggle()">abc</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button ng-disabled="mySwitch">def</button>
      <button ng-disabled="mySwitch">ghi</button>
    </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```