# How to disabled button on click and enabled it again if clicked at other button in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How do I achieve it? as per current now it seem that Angular only able to interact with single element, and not other element,

Example:

[image]

If clicked Home button, it will disabled home button,

If clicked Application button, it will enabled home button and disabled Application button

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button
              [routerLink]="['home']"
              routerLinkActive="active"
              class="btn btn-link"
              (click)="onClick(); home.disabled=true"
              #home
            >
              <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
              Home
            </button>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button
              [routerLink]="['app']"
              routerLinkActive="active"
              class="btn btn-link"
              (click)="onClick(); app.disabled=true"
              #app
            >
              <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
              Application
            </button>
          </li>
</ul>
```

**Updated 1:** I done something like this, it have delay on disabled the element here, but Jquery seem to be easier to achieve this, guess I switching back to use jquery instead of angular

**Update 2:** I had change to something like this, is this how angular do it? Am I doing correct? is there any simple way to do it?

**Final working solution**

```
 export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
      isActive = false;

    onClick() {
    
        const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-link');

        for(var b of btns){
          (<HTMLElement>b).removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
       
    
     
      }
        
        }
```

Comment: You can wrapper a method when do click, (click)="onHomeClicked()",  and do some logic in your component to interact with other element's binding..

Comment: see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: this one may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621350/how-can-i-disable-other-buttons-when-i-press-one-button-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

As you have **routerLinkActive** Try this

```
<button [routerLink]="['home']" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-link" #home="routerLinkActive" [disabled]="home.isActive">
```

Comment: this is only disabled the current  click, I want to enable other but only disable the 1 it click, if I click another 1, then the previous disabled button should be enabled back, the final is the 1 that I had achieve, which come from jquery background, Angular sure take a lot of code to achieve the 1 I need

Comment: Same thing you need to implement in other buttons `#home="routerLinkActive" [disabled]="home.isActive"` only need to change `home` for others and disable and enable will change according to `isActive`